# How to write to Mac OSX preference files with mono C#

Tags: macos, mono

Ii am looking for a guide and information to specifically reading from and writing to Mac OS 10.6, 10.7, and 10.8 preference files using preferably C# Mono.  However I am by far and large not picky and can pick up any other language to do the same thing.

Yes this is probably a duplicate question, I just haven't had the time to research it myself.  I am not "just wanting the answer handed to me" because honestly that is not going to teach me anything in the long run.  Thank you for your help and suggestions ^_^

Edit: BTW, working 8-10 hour days makes it difficult to do much of anything else.  I have done some searching on and off and while I have found sparse materials on coding preferences for Mac in the Mac docs and a couple tuts here and there, there still is not much in the way of Mono driven preferences specifically.  I will be checking out the answer with MonoMac, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there an API in the Mac OS SDK to do this?

If yes, chances are that this API is wrapped by [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac), and then you can just use that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has been difficult finding materials specifically on this topic.